# React-Native flatlist VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews

Tags: javascript, react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist

Hy, I'm new in react-native. I'm stuck in the flatlists and scrollView. Here's the structure of my code:

```
<View>
    <ScollView>
        <View>
            <SafeAreaView>
                <FlatList/> -- Horizontal Scroll --
            </SafeAreaView>
        </View>
        <View>
        </View>
        <View>
            <FlatList/> -- Horizontal Scroll --
        </View>
        <View>
            <FlatList/> -- Horizontal Scroll -- //Issue        
        </View>
    </ScollView>
</View>
```

So the issue flatlist mentioned above like **//Issue**. The issue is that when I add the flatlist which is need to scroll in vertical format its not scrolling and one more thing this flatlist is displaying at the middle of screen so to start the working I add the height and its start working but the functionality I want is that When I scroll the screen should move to down. So do this i add the scrollView as you in above structure but when I add scrollView I remove the height it start working perfectly but displaying that error:

**VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation because it can break windowing and other functionality - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead.**

So to solved this I try:

1. nestedScrollEnable={true}
2. scrollEnabled
3. giving height
4. When I start working on this app I also face same issue then I get the solution using ListHeaderComponent and ListFooterComponent. But now my already code in Header and Footer component.

but I can't solve. If some have some idea then share it. I would appreciate your favor

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the `React-Native`, it is not ideal to use **FlatList** inside the **ScrollView**. What you can do instead is, to use **nested scroll view**. The only thing which is going to be changed is you have to do `.map()`, and populate the data inside the `ScrollView` inspite of `renderItem` from `FlatList`, and every thing will else will work just fine.

- Use `flexGrow: 1`, inside the `ScrollView`, then no `height` is required.

**Your Structure now should be:**

```
<View style={{flex: 1}} >
    <ScollView style={{flexGrow: 1}} 
     nestedScrollEnabled={true}>
        <View>
            <SafeAreaView>
                <ScrollView horizontal 
                style={{width: '100%', height: 'your_height'}}>
                  {data.map(item, index) => (
                    <View key={index}>
                      // Your component
                    </View>
                  )}
                </ScrollView> -- Horizontal Scroll --
            </SafeAreaView>
        </View>
        <View>
        </View>
        <View>
            <ScrollView horizontal 
            style={{width: '100%', height: 'your_height'}}>
                  {anotherData.map(item, index) => (
                    <View key={index}>
                      // Your component
                    </View>
                  )}
            </ScrollView> -- Horizontal Scroll --
        </View>
        <View>
            <ScrollView horizontal
            style={{width: '100%', height: 'your_height'}}>
                  {newData.map(item, index) => (
                    <View key={index}>
                      // Your component
                    </View>
                  )}
            </ScrollView> -- Horizontal Scroll --      
        </View>
    </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this. It worked well for me

Answer (score 3):

as both flatlist and scrollView have vertical direction thats why it is giving error . what you need to do is that encolose your flatlist in another scrollview and make its direction horizontal like that

```
<ScrollView horizontal={true} contentContinaerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}>
    <FlatList>
</ScrollView>
```

here by using flexGrow 1 the scrollView will takeup full width

Answer (score 0):

Adding `scrollEnabled={false}` directive to the `FlatList` resolved the issue for me in React Native 0.72.3.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your question with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using FlatList, I rendered the list with the help of `map`

```
  <ScrollView>
    other components
    {
        list.map((item) => <ListItem key={item.id} item={item}/>)
    }
    other components
  </ScrollView>
```

This solution works great if you have a small list to render but larger list will give you performance and memory issues